# как в консоли создать доп.колонку при выводе

Tags: mysql

у меня есть учителя, ученики и курсы.
я смог вывести имя и возраст учеников и учителей и мне нужно создать доп колонку для курсов(их длительность) просто длительность курсов записываются как age

```
(SELECT name, age FROM students ORDER BY age ASC limit 3)
    -> UNION
    -> (SELECT name,age FROM teachers ORDER BY age DESC limit 3)
    -> UNION
    -> (SELECT name, duration FROM courses ORDER BY duration DESC limit 3);
```

[image: последние 3 курса, их длительность записана в столбик age]

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT name, age, NULL duration FROM students ORDER BY age ASC limit 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT name, age, NULL FROM teachers ORDER BY age DESC limit 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT name, NULL, duration FROM courses ORDER BY duration DESC limit 3);
```